# Imports and wildcard imports of Symbols in Scala

Tags: class, scala, macros, import, scala-macros

I have a list of Symbols representing packages, objects and classes and want to import them in a macro context.

For packages and objects, this would mean a wildcard import and for classes it would mean a “standard” import.

Given a `List[Symbol]` consisting of `some.package`, `some.Class` and `some.Object`, how would I properly import those and how can I  decide whether a “standard” or a wildcard import needs to be used?

My current approach is this:

```
def importPackageOrModuleOrClass(sym: Symbol): Import =
  if (sym.isPackage || sym.isModule) // e. g. import scala._, scala.Predef
    gen.mkWildcardImport(sym)
  else                               // e. g. import java.lang.String
    gen.mkImport(sym.enclosingPackage, sym.name, sym.name) // <--- ?????
```

The package/module import works, but the class import doesn't although it looks correct.

Comment: I've not done this with the `TreeGen` stuff, but if you were writing this in a regular old macro, you'd need to change `sym.name` (which is currently a `TypeName`) into a `TermName`.

Comment: How would one do that? I think I tried `asTerm`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Here's [a quick example](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/5948460) that combines your code with an experiment I was working on a while back. The same thing gets printed whether you convert the `TypeName` to a `TermName` or not, but only the `TermName` version works.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out! `gen.mkImport(sym.enclosingPackage, sym.name.toTermName, sym.name.toTermName)` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the *"TermName"* like this...

```
def importPackageOrModuleOrClass(sym: Symbol): Import =
if (sym.isPackage || sym.isModule)
    gen.mkWildcardImport(sym)
else
    gen.mkImport(sym.enclosingPackage, sym.name.toTermName, sym.name.toTermName)
```

You can grab more hints regarding importing, reflecting, etc. via the sourcecode at http://xuwei-k.github.io/scala-compiler-sxr/scala-compiler-2.10.0/scala/reflect/internal/Importers.scala.html